# Are there fractional solutions for Pell-Fermat equations?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Trying to solve a problem I meet on the way a question, easy maybe, that I can't solve for now. The Pell-Fermat equation $$x^2-dy^2=1 \hspace{2cm}(*)$$ where the integer $d$ is square-free, has in general infinitely many integer solutions for which the fundamental unit of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt d)$ is the key. In fact,   all the integer solutions $(x_n,y_n)$ of $(*)$ are given by$$x_n+y_n\sqrt d=(x_1+y_1\sqrt d)^n;\space n\ge 1$$ where $ x_1+y_1\sqrt d$ is the mentioned fundamental unit.

The punctual question is, **are there non-integer rational solutions $(x,y)$ with $xy\ne0$ for $x^2-3y^2=1?$**

(*All the integer solutions are given by $x_n+y_n\sqrt3=(2+\sqrt3)^n$*)

Comment: All the integer solutions are given by $x_n + y_n\sqrt{3} = \pm(2+\sqrt{3})^n$ for $n$ in $\mathbf Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of thing is parametrized by a finite number of recipes of the Pythagorean triple type.  It is **not necessarily** parametrized by just one  recipe.  A reference is Mordell, *Diophantine Equations*, page 47, Theorem 4.

Multiplying through be common denominator $w$   leads to integers $u,v,w$ with
$$  u^2 - 3 v^2 = w^2 $$  or
$$  u^2 = 3 v^2 + w^2 \; . \;$$

If, in turn, we demand $u,v,w$  coprime, ...  with coprime integers $m,n:$

When $u$ is even we get all solutions by
$$ u = 2 m^2 + 2mn + 2 n^2 \;, \; \; v = m^2 + 2mn \; , \; \; w = -m^2 + 2mn + 2 n^2 \; . \; $$

When $u$ is odd we get all solutions by
$$ u = 3 m^2  +  n^2 \;, \; \; v =  2mn \; , \; \; w = 3m^2  - n^2 \; . \; $$

In the first one we need $m$ odd, not sure about conditions $\pmod 3$

In the second one we need $m+n$ odd and $ n \neq 0\pmod 3$

Comment: Thanks you. This question can be related to an elementary answer to the problem you have solved with " heavy artillery" (in which not- mentioned elliptic curves are involved) in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4525135/a2-b2-c2-ab-6d2-a-b-1-has-no-solutions-a-b-c-d-in-mat . In fact we have the equation $$(a+b)^2-3(2d)^2=c^2$$ for which the integer solutions of $x^2-3y^2=1$ are not good.

Comment: @Piquito   I found a good answer  to that one at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4218013/why-p-equiv-3-mod-8-is-not-a-congruent-number/4222489#4222489  by Dan Fulea

Comment: Thank you very much for the interesting link. The “objection” to the post of a respectable MSE member made me smile: “Are not congruent to what?”